# Is there a name for shapes that can be cut out on a bandsaw?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, terminology, convex-geometry

Let $S$ be some subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\text{Conv}(S)$ be its convex hull. Say $S$ has property $\mathcal{P}$ if each point $x \notin S$ lies on some line contained in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S$ such that there is a ruled surface in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S$ giving a homotopy to a line in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \text{Conv}(S)$. Intuitively you can think of this as saying that $S$ can be cut out on a bandsaw. Is there a name for this property or a simpler equivalent form?

My motivation for this is wanting to define the $\mathcal{P}$-hull of a subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ to be the smallest set containing $S$ that has property $\mathcal{P}$ (which is well-defined since the intersection of sets with property $\mathcal{P}$ has property $\mathcal{P}$). For example if $S$ is the wireframe of a compound of two tetrahedra as below, its convex hull is a cube, but its $\mathcal{P}$-hull is a stellated octahedron.

[image]

(I would also be interested in the stronger property where the ruled surface is replaced with a planar region between the lines. Intuitively the shapes with this property would be those that can be cut out on a bandsaw with only straight cuts.)

Comment: Apollonius (of Perga), of conic section fame, would be proud!

Comment: (+1) Just to note, at risk of mathematical pedantry: (i) A convex set such as a ball has property $\mathcal{P}$, but "requires infinitely many bandsaw cuts"; (ii) a cube "sliced partway through by a helicoid" has property $\mathcal{P}$, but cannot be cut by a physical bandsaw because a real blade is not a line; (iii) certain unbounded regions, such as the "outside" of a right angle between two half-planes can arguably be cut by a bandsaw, but the convex hull is all of space, so such a region does not have property $\mathcal{P}$ as currently stated.

Comment: Defining a hull will be difficult as, unlike with convex sets, there isn't a unique minimal $\mathcal{P}$-set covering any given set. For example, in $\Bbb{R}^2$, take a simple circle (not a disc, but its boundary). The convex hull, a disc, will have property $\mathcal{P}$ (trivially), as will a hemisphere with that circle as a boundary. If we take a proper subset of either set, we must tear a hole, which will prevent property $\mathcal{P}$. So, both sets could both lay claim to being a $\mathcal{P}$-hull of the circle.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yeah, the bandsaw analogy was just for intuition, I'm more interested in the idealized property itself than its physical realizability. I appreciate pedantry though :)

Comment: @TheoBendit I don't think the hemisphere actually does have property $\mathcal{P}$, its convex hull does (since a point in the interior of the convex hull doesn't have any line passing through it that misses the hemisphere). And the convex hull of a hemisphere has the disk as a subset, so this doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: In general, the intersection of any two subsets $A$ and $B$ with property $\mathcal{P}$ should always have property $\mathcal{P}$, since a ruled surface that misses one of the subsets certainly misses both, and the convex hull of $A \cap B$ is a subset of the intersection of the convex hulls of $A$ and $B$. So, you can define the $\mathcal{P}$-hull of $S$ as the intersection of all sets containing $S$ that have property $\mathcal{P}$ just as you do for convex hulls.

Comment: (I suppose technically I should consider an arbitrary intersection there, instead of an intersection of two sets, but the argument is the same.)

Comment: @Chris Yes, the disc and hemisphere both have property $\mathcal{P}$. Their intersection is the circle, which, correct me if I'm wrong, does not have property $\mathcal{P}$. My point is that both the disc and the hemisphere are both "$\mathcal{P}$-hulls" of the circle, in the sense that any strict subset of either, still containing the circle, will not have property $\mathcal{P}$; the will be a hole. Also, just realised, my previous comment has a typo: I'm considering the circle in $\Bbb{R}^3$, not in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think you may be misunderstanding the property, why do you think the hemisphere satisfies property $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: @Chris I somehow misread your first reply, twice. I thought you were agreeing that it had property $\mathcal{P}$! Anyway, as I understood it, every line that passes through the convex hull of the hemisphere, but not the hemisphere itself, has a homotopy to a line not passing through the convex hull. There are no such lines, so the property vacuously holds. What am I missing?

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah I see what you're saying. Property $\mathcal{P}$ requires every point $x \notin S$ to lie on some line in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus S$, so there's no way for the property to hold vacuously. In particular, since there are no such lines for points in the interior of the convex hull of the hemisphere, it does not satisfy property $\mathcal{P}$.